# Javascript remove the occurrences of item by matching condition

Tags: javascript

I have an arrray as below:

```
var testArr = [ "1,A", "2,B",  "1,D", "3,A" ]
```

I would like to get the result as

```
var result = [ "1,A", "2,B", "3,A" ]
```

I have tried to using filter but I cannot get the output. Could anyone please help me for this?

Comment: To clarify, are those strings in the array? So: "1,A" and "2,B" are strings? Do you only want to remove the string "1,D"?

Comment: const result = testArr.filter(el => el !== "1,D")

Comment: which condition ?

Comment: Yes they are String @Sebastian

Comment: I would like to remove all items which has "1" in the array except the first occurrence item @Nick

Comment: You want to do something like: 1. create a new set breaking the components apart so they can be considered separately ie "1,A" becomes `{key:"1", value:"A"}`, 2. group the results by the `value` property, 3. use that to create an array of the key values and the first group list item, 4. finally use those results to remap the object back to the original "1,A" type strings. Something like this would work: `Object.entries(["1,A","2,B","1,D","3,A"].map(i=>({k:i.split(',')[0],v:i.split(',')[1]})).reduce((a,v)=>{if(!a[v.k]){a[v.k]=[];}a[v.k].push(v.v);return a;}, {})).map(e=>\`${e[0]},${e[1][0]}\`)`

Comment: If my array is: var testArr = [ "1,A,D" , "2,B",  "1,D", "3,A,C" ] how should I use solution? @asawyer

Comment: @HaiPham The array index bits would need to change. Instead of assuming the split would only produce two items it would need to be smarter about the values bit, making it a set of everything past the first (array slice makes that simple) and the final bit converting back to a string would need to do a join instead of the [1][0] index acessor.

Comment: @HaiPham Well that assumes if the set is `["1,A,A",  "1,A,B", "1,B,A"]` that only output would be `["1,A,A"]`. If the "uniqueness" depends on not just the 'key' part of the string but instead has criteria based on contained values in the following data the `reduce` function would need to take that into account. Ie if in that case the correct result is in fact `["1,A,A","1,B,A"]` as the `"1,A,B"` is omitted due to sharing the "A" with the first item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const testArr = ['1,A', '2,B', '1,D', '3,A'];

const result = testArr.reduce((val, cur) => {
  if (!val.some((v) => v.includes(cur[0]))) {
    val.push(cur);
  }
  return val;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

var newra = oldra.filter(compare_function);

The above function 'filter' creates a new empty array and iterates through the elements in oldra. If the elements value when passed to compare_function(element_value) returns true, it will be added to the new array otherwise it will be skipped. The filter function continues iterating through the oldra building a new array as it goes until all elements are processed. The filter function then returns the new array.

The compare_function(element_value) expects the value of an element of an array to be passed to it. The programmer performs some calculation on the element_value and returns a true or false based on this calculation according to whether it should be included in the newra or not.